# Ubuntu 16.04.3, hang on restart after install, hang on first boot

Tags: boot, 16.04, nvidia

I am struggling to install Ubuntu LTS on my laptop.

Once the installation has complete, you get the usual you can now restart. Once you click restart the system just crashes so you then must perform a hard reset.

On the next boot, you get manufacturers bios splash, purple background and crash. Tried three installations.

I am running I7 7700HQ, 16GB ram, 1TB HDD, GTX 1050.

I have tried 17.04 and this works fine, but I want LTS installed.

Can anyone offer any assistance?

Comment: Same deal for me, 16.04.3 hangs intermittently on login, and always on reboot/shutdown. I have a Clevo P950HP which has very similar specs, and the same CPU. It might be the kernel version, what are you running? I'm on 4.10.0-35-generic (type `uname -a` in a terminal to find out).

Comment: I figured it was the kernel, I decided to install Linux mint as that currently uses kernel 4.8, I now have zero issues.